# Flex XML E4X Checking for atribute==value

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, search, e4x

So I've got an xml like this stored in a variable in Flex AS3

```
var xm:XML=<licenses>
                <license id="7" name="No known copyright restrictions" url="http://flickr.com/commons/usage/" />
                <license id="4" name="Attribution License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" />
                <license id="6" name="Attribution-NoDerivs License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/" />
                <license id="3" name="Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/" />
                <license id="2" name="Attribution-NonCommercial License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/" />
                <license id="1" name="Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/" />
                <license id="5" name="Attribution-ShareAlike License" url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" />
            </licenses>
```

And the Flickr API is returning the license of a photo, which is parsed and put in an object. Lets say the license Id for a particular photo is accessible as

```
myPhoto.licenseId;
```

How do I look for which license belongs to the given licenseId?

I've tried

```
var x1:Object=(xm.licenses.license.name.(@id==myPhoto.licenseId.toString()));
var x2:Object=(xm.license.name.(@id==myPhoto.licenseId.toString()));
var x3:Object=(xm.licenses.license.(@id==myPhoto.licenseId.toString()));
```

But they all return an empty `XMLList`

Also, not putting the `toString()` gives the same result.

Been stuck on this for a few hours now and it gets more frustrating everytime I think about it. Any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Doh! monster strikes again!!

I now notice I was trying to access `xm.licenses.license`. This is wrong because `<licenses>` is the root for the xml. The correct one is

```
xm.license.(@id==myPhoto.licenseId.toString());
```